# I have to identify paragraphs from multiple text files(.txt) and create a dataframe of [paragraph1, "text of the file1 in paragraphs "]

Tags: python, nlp, stanford-nlp

```
with open("/home/xxxx/Downloads/DataEnginner9.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

when i run this code i am able to get as sentences only,

The above code takes the file and splits into sentences and prints each line, but i want it to identify paragraphs from multiple files and also create a data-frame which contains the file name in the first column and respective entire content in the second column of the same row
i.e..,
example Data-frame :

[file1,content of the file splitted in paragraphs;
file2,content of the file2 splitted in paragraphs
.
.
.
]

Below is the sample output generated by the above script from one file.

> Job description
>
> Responsibilities
>
> Work collaboratively with a global team to design, develop
>
> scalable, maintainable and reliable services that process very large
>   quantities
>
> data using Big Data technologies (100 billion daily indicators, 6
>   TB/day before
>
> compression).
>
> Familiar with Object oriented development, with specific experience
>
> in at least one major OO language(knowledge of Java is mandatory and
>   if
>
> possible java 8). Nice to have: Knowledge of functional programming.
>
> Perform end-to-end software development life cycle functions
>
> including Design, Development, Performance Analysis & Tuning,
>   Optimization,
>
> Testing and Product Maintenance.

Comment: Hi - what have you tried to combine the lines into paragraphs? Edit your code into your question and explain what is does and wha you want it to do.

Comment: Yes i have updated with required output. As a dataframe which have to consist of a file name and the respective content of the file represented as a paragraph from multiple text files

Comment: If all your code is in your question, then it's not obvious that you have made any attempt to solve the problem - all you do is print the lines from the file. StackOverflow isn't a code-writing service so you need to do some work to process the lines. Good luck!

Comment: I have tried a lots of  other ways also by writing an regular expression also Kindly see the code which i will be posting, the issue is even if i try to split into lines i am not able to split in the level of paragraphs

Answer (score 0):

```
def txt(filepath):
    df12 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["title","paragraphs"])
    af = []
    with open(filepath) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    paragraph = ''
    for line in lines:
        if line.isspace():  # is it an empty line?
            if paragraph:
                af.append(paragraph)
                paragraphs = re.split("\n\n(?=\u2028|[A-Z-0-9])", af)
                paragraph = ''
            else:
                continue
        else:
            paragraph += ' ' + line.strip()
    return paragraphs
```